# Extracting values from terminal output

Tags: c++11, terminal, ubuntu-14.04

[image: terminal_output]

Hi everyone, I need a C++ script to extract only the time's value from this terminal output (for example 0.019 0.019 0.024 etc.) and to do it for every line while I'm pinging. Any ideas how this can be achieved? Thank you!

Comment: Why C++? Pipe through awk would be straightforward.

Comment: Here is the sourcecode of the unix ping tool if you want to send the ICMP packets yourself: http://www.ping127001.com/pingpage/ping.text

Answer (score 3):

You can form a command as which will dump the **ping** result in a file and then you can get the time from the file.

```
std::string command ="ping 192.162.1.11 > myfile.txt"

system(command.c_str());
```

you will get result into myfile and then grep "time=" from the file.